# What is the most common way to represent a byte array in C?

Tags: python, arrays, c, ctypes

Would we use `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` or import some header for a `byte` type?

My code is going to be seen/used by other C developers and I want to use whatever standard they're most likely used to seeing.

Also, I may be allocating memory for this function from python as a numpy array and calling it through ctypes. Is there a preferred way to allocate a byte array in numpy?

Is `np.zeros(size, dtype=np.byte)` the normal way, if the corresponding C type is `char`, for example?

Comment: There is not standard way of representing a byte array. Not that I know of. Use whatever is appropriate for your case.

Comment: There are several different ways to accomplish this, and the one that I think is best depends on the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish. For instance, are you simply looking for the "natural" `char` representation in Python? Are you calling C code from your Python, or vice-versa? Are you already using Numpy for other things in your project?

Comment: @Goion What is appropriate for a compression library?

Comment: @jweightman I'm allocating memory for the C library in Python, and then calling the C code from Python. I'm not necessarily using numpy for anything else, it's just the standard way I've learned to allocate memory for C librarys called through ctypes.

Comment: I don't know. Never written a compression library. All I know that in the end `char`, and `signed char` both have 8 bits in them and the only thing that differentiates them is the operations performed on them. Like 127+1 would lead to overflow in one case and not in other case. Choose what is suitable for you.

Comment: What is useful to you? `>`, `*`, and `>>` all behave differently on similar bit patterns. Which behaviour do you want? Choose the one more appropriate to your needs.

Comment: @ikegami My question is meant to ask how I should represent the byte array in the interface/public header of the library. I can use any and all of the options in the implementation using casts to suit my binary arithmetic, but that implementation can be separate from the interface / public function arguments.

Comment: If you just want to cast anyway, just use `void*` like `malloc`, `read` and `write`

Comment: By defitition, you ask for options - and therefore your question is OT.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, hmmm? It asks which *one* of the options should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is using a char array.
However, it really depends on the needs of the code.